# Is it light that is first or darkness?

Tags: universe, enlightenment

A friend asked about what the existence of darkness in the universe is, and that it's white light instead of darkness. And I said if the universe was only white, how can you see all the planets or a person next to you and why does the light gives light in the dark. Is it black that is first or white light?

Comment: Light is energy. Darkness is the absence of, or negative, energy.

Comment: Neither. [Photon epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_epoch) started 10 seconds after the Big Bang, before that there is no sense to talking about light or darkness, they are anthropocentric metaphors that do not apply to "the universe". Even after that, most of light spectrum is invisible to us anyway, so it is neither black, nor white, nor any other color.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olbers%27_paradox

Comment: @Conifold I starred at the sun and clothed my eyes and suddenly I see a ball that is magenta in color in my mind which is the inverted color of green, and all grass and leaves are green. You can call it spectrum or additive colors and subtractive colors. In the abscence of light or spectrum what life would be on earth.

Comment: I am afraid, optical effects, and physical conditions of life on Earth have little to do with philosophy. Could you explain what you *philosophical* question is. Is "first" supposed to be metaphorical in some sense (since neither temporal nor causal sense makes much sense)? It is unclear what you are asking us.

Comment: If you have a reference that you or your friend are reading that would provide more context for the question. Welcome to Philosophy!

Comment: First there was nothing. Darkness assumes there exists a medium in which it can be dark.

Comment: @Mazura "a medium in which it can be dark" ? - Darkness is where there is no light coming at you.

Comment: Darkness-light is a spectrum. There is no first. Try ask yourself "What is first, big or small?" I hope you got the clue.

Comment: @rus9384 were you there to see the spectrum and how do you know there was nothing? Even reptiles including dinosaurs were big and they had three chambers in there heart. Humans are small and have eyes. Eyes have  colors in them called RGB. Energy in the body is RGB according to electromagnetic fields. Inverted colors of RGB are CYM. Were there waters present in the early universe and are they a spectrum?

Comment: I meant not the RGB spectrum like in humans, but that it is scale-like. What is first, cold or hot? What is first, 0 or 1? And so on. None of these things are meaningful on their own. If you speak about cold, you also have a concept of hot in the mind. Were everything dark, you simply would not have a word for it.

Comment: @rus9384 darkness absorbs light it doesn't reflect it ,therefore light is second to darkness although you might find a residue of energy to the darkness .

Comment: I think you might get further in your thinking if you study the Big Bang and the observations that lead to that model, and also this notion of branes.  With branes, cosmologists suppose that the first thing that differentiated our universe was our physical laws starting to exist: the physical laws that entail electromagnetic radiation (which De Broglie posited is no different from matter) or in other words, "light".  www.pcahistory.org/creation/report.html

Comment: No such thing as Big Bang.

Answer (score 2):

In Suhrawardis philosophy, light is the foundation of all being. This is a development on Al-Ghazalis *Niche of all Lights*, which takes as central a famous verse in the Qu'ran. The proximity or distance from the light of lights determines the ontic light reality of all beings. Reality proceeds from the light of lights, and unfolds via the first light and all subsequent lights whose exponentially increasing interactions brings about the phenomenal world.

In this view, we are akin to shards of transparent glass through which the light of lights illuminates and refracts into all the colours of being.

Comment: I'm going to quote from what Rene´ Descartes said "je pense je le suis" and in english "I think therefore I am" and the reference comes from the book of king Solomon's proverbs chapter 23 verse 7"as a man thinks in his heart so is he". From what I heard every person has a rainbow encircling him or her. So every human Have a light in them and the Law is a sword in the ground which represent a light.

Answer (score 1):

In general relativity's solution to [Olbers' paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olbers%27_paradox), the darkness can be interpreted as "the increasing separation between us and everything else."

Everywhere you look there is some light, but we see it dimmer now... so dimly that we just kind of call it "background": the cosmic microwave background.

Comment: But if you go out into the forest where there are practically no artificial lights and gaze up into the sky on a clear moonless night, you will see that the sky is *not* dark. It's incredibly sparkly, like a bejeweled velvet gown. There must be a lot of mass out there that hinders our vision such that we can't see all of the stars. Not to mention the fact that our eyes limit our vision to only particular wavelengths. The ability to perceive the full spectrum varies even between individuals. And as a species we don't have the physiological capacity to detect all of them with the naked eye.

Comment: @Bread I have seen  glowing white particles arround me sometimes, but I can't describe what they are and they disappear quickly. I don't know except they look like start trek tv shows where they say beam me up.

Comment: @user450072 I have no problem believing that, as my own vision is pretty good, too. :) I just thought of something though, with reference to this answer: I would generally agree that darkness does represent some form of separation. For that, I shall now give this answer a 1+.

Comment: Merci beaucoup.

Comment: @user450072 My mother used to see such glowing particles shortly before a migraine... At any rate, nothing _you see_ is the real world rather it is a representation of the world created by your brain. Anything you see should be confirmed as part of the 'real' world by other people.